# Do I need to share logger instance across modules in python project?

Tags: python, logging, flask, logrotate

I have a generic logger instance specific to my projects. It automatically creates and attaches 2 handlers (`StreamHandler` and `TimedRotatingFileHandler`) with different formatting etc. preconfigured to them.

```
logging_formatters = {
    'fmt': "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s:%(process)05d] [%(module)10s:%(lineno)03d] (%(name)s) %(message)s",
    'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}
def get_logger(
        application_name=None,
        filename=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs
):
    if not isinstance(application_name, str):
        raise ValueError("Logger class expects a string type application name")

    if filename is None:
        filename = application_name

    if not filename.endswith(".log"):
        filename = filename.split('.')[0] + ".log"

    log_path = kwargs.get('log_path')
    service_name = kwargs.get('service_name', '')
    console_level = kwargs.get('console_level', logging.INFO)
    file_level = kwargs.get('file_level', logging.DEBUG)

    logger = logging.getLogger(application_name)
    if len(logger.handlers) > 0:
        return logger
    # Create 2 handlers, and add them to the logger created
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
```

Now, suppose my flask project structure is something similar to:

```
/
- app.py
- settings.py
- dir1/
    - __init__.py
    - mod1.py
- dir2/
    - __init__.py
    - mod2.py
```

I start the server using `python app.py`. The `app.py` in itself imports the `dir1.mod1` and `dir2.mod2` modules. Each of those modules create their own logger instance as follows:

```
logger = log_package.get_logger(
    application_name='{}.{}'.format(settings.APPLICATION_NAME, __name__),
    filename=settings.LOG_FILE_NAME,
    service_name=settings.SERVICE_NAME,
)
```

and in case of `app.py` it is:

```
logger = log_package.get_logger(
    application_name='{}.{}'.format(settings.APPLICATION_NAME, 'run'),
    filename=settings.LOG_FILE_NAME,
    service_name=settings.SERVICE_NAME,
)
```

Now, the issue I am facing is that; the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` is working fine for all the submodules (namely, `dir1.mod1`, `dir2.mod2` etc.) however, the logs from `app.py` are not being rolled over to the new file. That particular instance is writing the logs to the same file as when the service was started. For eg. if I started the service on `2017-07-11`, then `app.py` will keep writing logs to `LOG_FILE_NAME.log.2017-07-11` whereas the other modules are rolling over everyday (`when=midnight`) and the new logs are being written to `LOG_FILE_NAME.log`.

What could be the issue behind **`TimedRotatingFileHandler`** not working for a particular file? I ran the `lsof` command for all files in the directory, and this was the output:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
python  23795 ubuntu    4w   REG  202,1  2680401 150244 /path/to/LOG_FILE_NAME.2017-07-12
python  23795 ubuntu   33w   REG  202,1   397074 150256 /path/to/LOG_FILE_NAME.log
```

Do I need to share logger instance across modules in python project? I think this should not be required as logging module is threadsafe in itself.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimedRotatingHandler` instance shouldn't be writing to a file other than `LOG_FILE_NAME.log` - the other files such as `LOG_FILE_NAME.2017-07-12` would be created when rolling over, and shouldn't be left open.

You should ensure that you have only one `TimedRotatingFileHandler` instance in your process for a given filename - if you have two different handler instances both referencing the same filename, you may get unexpected behaviour (if one instance rolls over, it changes the file it's using, but the other instance will still have a reference to the old file, and keep writing to that).

You should probably just attach your handlers to the root logger, rather than individual module loggers, and the other loggers would pick those handlers up, under default conditions (loggers' default `propagate` settings not changed).

**Update:** `%(name)s` always gives the name of the logger which was used for the logging call, even when the handlers are attached to an ancestor logger. If `propagate` is set to `False` for a logger, then the handlers in ancestor loggers aren't used - so you should leave `propagate` to its default value of `True`.

Comment: But I want the `%(name)s` to represent the name of logger. If someone (I share the `log_package` with a few colleagues) is creating a project `A`, they would represent all loggers in the project as `A.app`, `A.dir1.mod1`, ... and the log file would always be `A.log`. Towards the end of my function definition, I have overridden the propagate value: `logger.propagate = False`. Should I reset the `logger.propagate` to `True`?